# undefined local variable or method `interface' for #<#<Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Okay can some one please explain what this error message means, i personally think because my interface model is clean of columns, but the other side thinks it's because of params: :username.

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile" , interface.to_param %></li>


class Interface < ActiveRecord::Base
    def to_param
        username
    end
end
```

Controller

```
class InterfacesController < ApplicationController
    #before_action :authenticate_user!

    def show
        @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    end
end
```

routes

```
 devise_for :users
root 'posts#index'

  resources :interfaces, only: :show , param: :username

  resources :posts do 
    resources :comments
  end




create_table "interfaces", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: interface is undefined. you're using it in the view. you need to define it.

Answer (score 0):

This second link to argument should be where the url is.

```
 <li><%= link_to "Profile" , interface.to_param %></li>
```

Interface is undefined. Not sure what you're trying to do but run rake routes and insert the path you want that to link to there. Something like

```
      <li><%= link_to "Profile", interface_path(@interface) %></li>
```

and define @interface in the show action.

Comment: <pre>               interface GET    /interfaces/:username(.:format)             interfaces#show
<code> <pre> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"interfaces", :username=>nil} missing required keys: [:username]
<code><pre>  @interface = @user.interface.find_by(username: params[:username])
<code>i think i totally messed up with the interface defenition

Comment: you'll need to pass username as a param to the path, just like @interface. Also--your find_by should be username: params[:username] or :username => params[:username]

re: code in comments...I don't know.

Comment: what did you use for user auth? do you have current_user? if so...it would be something like: <li><%= link_to "Profile", interface_path(id: @interface, username: current_user.username) %></li> assuming a user has a username and you have current_user.

Comment: @toddmethey no i didn't user current_user, and i'm using devise, and btw every thing was working gr8 before i noticed that the link_to wasn't working properly, and what i want is /interfaces/users_username

Comment: devise has current_user...it's built in. Make sure you're getting the path helper correct. Run rake routes to see all the path helpers.

Comment: you were totally right...thank you i don't know why i forgot that i want the link to be available to the current_user, for some reason i wanted it to be available for all users....meh time to sleep, and thank you again